# I used this code for displaying 4 numbers randomly without repeating, but i got error as resource id#3

Tags: php

I used this code for displaying 4 numbers randomly without repeating, but i got error as resource id#3

```
$test = nonRepeat(0,4,4); //calling function nonrepeat defined earlier
for ( $i = 0; $i < 4; $i++ ) {
   $result = mysql_query( "select * from abc where id='test[i]'" ); accessing data from data base as id in the array test.
   print_r( $result ); 
}
```

Comment: What's this supposed to do -- `where id='test[i]`? Anyway, resource id #3 is not an error message -- that means the query is getting executed and it's returning a valid resource.

Comment: replace test[i] by $test[$i]

Answer (score 1):

1.- Don't use *mysql_** functions they are deprecated and will not be included in future updates.

2.- Your question is pretty unclear, but when you execute a query using `mysql_query` you get a resource, so you need to iterate through this:

```
$test = nonRepeat(0,4,4); //calling function nonrepeat defined earlier
for($i=0;$i<4;$i++)
{
    $result = mysql_query( "select * from abc where id='{$test[i]}'" ); <<<---- CHANGED
    if ($result){
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            print_r($row); //Display each row data
        }
    }else{
       print "Error:" . mysql_error();
    }
}
```

Try this and see what is showing, and take a look to [mysqli_](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) and [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't print anything...